# Serve image with encrypted src url

Tags: image, encryption, protected

I'm trying to display an image with an encrypted url. The src url looks something like `src="http://domain.name/?ACT=80&key=ZgcgFipjWAdoP9qc"`. But obviously browsers can't handle this sort of url construct as an image's source.

Is there any way I can achieve what I'm looking to do? Is there an htaccess rule that could force browsers to process the url? Or do I need to find a way first to process the encrypted link into an image, and then pass that into the `src=` attribute?

Any pointers most welcome!

Comment: I don't understand, what sort of construct is it? This URL is fine for every browser. Do you mean that data behind the URL is encrypted and you want to decrypt it? Right now, it reads like the URL is "encrypted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
src="http://domain.name/serve_image.php?ACT=80&key=ZgcgFipjWAdoP9qc"
```

this has worked for me

and you wont need .htaccess either :)

Comment: ah. So I do have to process the url path via a small php script. Thanks, much appreciated.